# undo effect of ASCII ftp transfer

Tags: images, ftp, conversion

I wonder whether is any sript / software which is capable to undo the effect of the ASCII ftp transfer of binary files (jpeg images)

Comment: Why don't you set your client to binary mode before downloading the files?

Comment: It's not me. I am just handling damage control. Anyway, I've figured it out.

Comment: @ts01 - Please delete this question if you no longer want an answer, or even better answer the question yourself.

Comment: @Nifle just doin'

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems to be quite simple, given I knew source and target OS (linux & windows), it was as simple as changing all "\r\n" to "\n"